# Unable to see the validation and test performance plot in a custom neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have made a function "neuralnetfunc" which takes cell array input and target to make a neural network. This is a multilayer perceptron.

I have used data division function. Unfortunately, I can not view the testing and validation performance plots in matlab.

Please help me to find a way to view the validation and test performence .

Thanks,
Hirak

```
yy(1:90)=1; 
X=mat2cell(FeatureSpec,[1 1 1 1 1 1 1],yy);
T=mat2cell(tgt,[1],yy);

[ysim,net]=neuralnetfunc(X,tgt);




function[Y,net]=neuralnetfunc(X,T)

net= network;
% number of inputs in the input layer
net.numInputs = 7;
net.numLayers = 10;
% Bias are connected to every neural net
net.biasConnect=[1; 1; 1; 1; 1;1 ; 1; 1 ; 1; 1];

% How inputs are connected
net.inputConnect(1,1) = 1;
net.inputConnect(2,2) = 1;
net.inputConnect(3,3) = 1;
net.inputConnect(4,4) = 1;
net.inputConnect(5,5) = 1;
net.inputConnect(6,6) = 1;
net.inputConnect(7,7) = 1;

% How layers are connected
net.layerConnect(8,1)=1;
net.layerConnect(8,2)=1;
net.layerConnect(8,3)=1;

net.layerConnect(9,4)=1;
net.layerConnect(9,5)=1;
net.layerConnect(9,6)=1;
net.layerConnect(9,7)=1;

net.layerConnect(10,8)=1;
net.layerConnect(10,9)=1;


net.outputConnect = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

net.layers{1}.size = 1;
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{1}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{2}.size = 1;
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{2}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{3}.size = 1;
net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{3}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{4}.size = 1;
net.layers{4}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{4}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{5}.size = 1;
net.layers{5}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{5}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{6}.size = 1;
net.layers{6}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{6}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{7}.size = 1;
net.layers{7}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{7}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{8}.size = 4;
net.layers{8}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{8}.initFcn = 'initnw';


net.layers{9}.size = 4;
net.layers{9}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{9}.initFcn = 'initnw';

net.layers{10}.size = 1;
net.layers{10}.transferFcn = 'logsig';
net.layers{10}.initFcn = 'initnw'   ;

net.initFcn = 'initlay';


net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';
net.divideMode = 'sample';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.8;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.1;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.1;
net.performFcn = 'mse';
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';
net.trainParam.epochs=5000;
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...    
'plotregression', 'plotfit'}; 

net = train(net,X,T);



Y = sim(net,X);

end
```

Comment: "I have used data division function" - where? Also is your function output `ysim` or `Y` as there appears to be disagreement in your first and last lines. Your code doesn't appear to use any testing or validation data at any point...

Comment: 'Y = sim(net,X);' in this sentence I am just simulating the ANN, this code will work without Y also. with the whole data set.   and   the main data division occurs during training by the  lines.. 'net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';
net.divideMode = 'sample';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 0.8;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0.1;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0.1; 'My main problem is  these lines are not showing its effect...It should occur  in the GUI which appears after ' net = train(net,X,T);' command. In previous versions of matlab ( cant remember may- 9 or 10) it used to show 3 performence graph

Comment: Please help me if I am wrong in specifying data division function also.. I have used random data division function

Comment: Then surely the data you are looking for are stored in the `net` object after you call `net = train(net,X,T);`?

Comment: ok I solved it... It is the fact of the input as structure type. A matrix type input solves the problem in train function